# Run a javascript timer only once on aspx page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, timer

I have a function in my Site.Master page that displays a popup after 30 sec. But each time I load a subpage the timer statrs over and pops up again after the 30 sec.

I need it to display once, the whole time they are visiting the website. here is my code.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // run event......
}, 30000);
```

Comment: You will need to store a session variable, a cookie or write to localStorage to persist this value across post-backs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably would be easiest to use a session cookie to determine if the user has already seen the message:

```
if(!document.cookie.match(/sawMessage/)) {
   setTimeout(function() {
     // run event......
     document.cookie="sawMessage=true";
   }, 30000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting a flag, for example in a local storage:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("popup") != "1") {

   localStorage.setItem("popup", "1");

   setTimeout(function() {
    // run event......
   }, 30000);
}
```

EDIT:

If you want to make sure that popup would show up at least once, use this version instead:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("popup") != "1") {
   setTimeout(function() {
      localStorage.setItem("popup", "1");
      // run event......
   }, 30000);
}
```

this way the flag will only be set if popup actually shows.

Comment: What if they navigate to a different page prior to the 30 second timeout? They would never see the message

Comment: @RobM. then the `localStorage.setItem` will just have to be inside of timeout. Will update the answer